# how ${buildroot} is created automatically during rpmbuild?

Tags: centos6, rpmbuild

I want to create the binary rpm files from generated binary packages in centos 6.4 and noticed in one of my build system the `${buildroot}` is created automatically, I want to know how it can be achieved.

The sample `wget.spec` looks like below. detail spec is in my gist https://gist.github.com/larrycai/1ffe134bce1860f1cf87

```
%install
tar xf ~/wget.tar.gz -C %{buildroot}/

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/usr/bin/wget
```

The `wget.tar.gz` can be created `tar -zcvf ~/wget.tar.gz /usr/bin/wget`

When I build it using `rpmbuild -bb wget.spec`, I got the

```
+ rpmbuild -bb wget.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VNDZg4
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.S8koPW
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.12-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.12-1.x86_64
++ dirname /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.12-1.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.12-1.x86_64
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ tar xf /home/larry/wget.tar.gz -C /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.12-1.x86_64/
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
... (it is successful)
```

I wonder why line `mkdir /home/larry/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.12-1.x86_64` is executed automatically.

Are there any script or rpmmacros is enabled for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that build machines installed `redhat-rpm-config` package, the detail list below

This macro setting is in `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros`

```
%__spec_install_pre %{___build_pre}\
    [ "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" != "/" ] && rm -rf "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}"\
    mkdir -p `dirname "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"`\
    mkdir "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"\
%{nil}
```

We can either install this package or put this macros into `~/.rpmmacros`

I find it by running command `rpmbuild --showrc` can see that `mkdir` code segment is there, so I start to check whether there is special package is installed.